# JSON parameter that includes whitespace

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest

An XMLHTTPRequest is failing to run, because of what looks like a problem with there being whitespace in some of the JSON parameters requests.

The requests in the 4th & 5th lines of code below are an example of the syntax with and without space.

```
function procReq(e) { 
    if (APIXHR.readyState == 4 && APIXHR.status == 200)     { 
    var resp = JSON.parse(APIXHR.responseText);         
    var Home = resp.data.game.TeamA_TeamB.Teams[0];    /// THIS WORKS 
    var Away = resp.data.game.Te amC_TeamD.Teams[1];    /// THIS DOESN'T
    document.getElementById("Home").innerHTML = Home;
    document.getElementById("Home").style.textTransform = "uppercase";
    document.getElementById("Away").innerHTML = Away;
```

Not sure if I'm missing a Regex to correct the syntax.

The function runs fine for those requests without the whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var Away = resp.data.game["Te amC_TeamD"].Teams[1];
```

**Explanation**

```js
var o = {
  "ke y": "value"
}

console.log(o["ke y"]);
//console.log(o.ke y); // It doesn't work!
```